# iOS, Can I schedule a local notification and notice it in AppDelegate with the app running in background?

Tags: swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I'm using local and silent remote notifications in the app I'm working at work. I need to launch some methods according to events received from our servers or from the app itself via silent remote and local notifications respectively. I have no problem with remote notifications with the app in foreground, background or with the notification touched but I can't get the scheduled **local notifications** to be noticed by AppDelegate if the app is running in background (I mean, without user tapping the banner).

Is this even possible? If yes, which parameter should I add to the notification or what method is supposed to be called when it arrives?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to send a local notification that runs silently and starts your app.  The normal way to do things like this is Background App Refresh:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

You have no control of the time.  iOS will periodically give you short slices of time

Comment: mmmh, yeah, thank you, but the point is that events must be triggered locally (otherwise our backend will send a silent notification). I guess there's no way to do this.